# what tables does magento giftcard write to

Tags: magento

I am trying to find out that when creating a new magento giftcard, which tables are involved and what tables the new records are written to and the relations between the tables.
I'd appreciate any directions on that

Magento ver. 1.10.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place to start would be looking at the install scripts for gift cards in /app/code/core/Enterprise/Giftcard/sql/enterprise_giftcard_setup and /app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftCardAccount/sql/enterprise_giftcardaccount_setup

These will give you an idea of how the giftcard tables are structured and how their foreign keys interact with other tables in the system when gift cards are created and used.